# Modulo arithmetic rule

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I remember that:

$ab \equiv n \pmod p$

can be written as:

$((a \text{ mod } p) \cdot (b \text{ mod } p)) \text{ mod } p = n \text{ mod } p$

Applying the modulo to the factors of the product and I found PDFs calling this "Homomorphic Rule" (*Homomorphieregel*):

http://www.math.tu-dresden.de/~ganter/inf2009/05Diskrete09Drucker.pdf
http://www.math.tu-dresden.de/~ganter/inf0708/folien/inf07-Modulo.pdf

However, I cannot seem to wrap my head around why this is the case. It should even be intuitive, I think. How can I conclude that this works and remember it in an intuitive way?

I've already thought about Euklid's lemma, but don't know how to apply it to conclude what I want to conclude:

$p \mid cd \Rightarrow (p \mid c) \vee (p \mid d)$

But since there is an additional $n$ in the congruence, I think it cannot be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case $n \pmod p$ seems to be the remainder (Rest) operator, i.e. $n\pmod p$ is the remainder of the division $n$ divided by $p$. Stated in another way, there is an $n'$ so that

$$n'p+[n\pmod p]=n.$$

Now say we have $a,b$ and $a\pmod p$ and $b\pmod p$ are the remainders when dividing by $p$. This means there are $a',b'$ so that

\begin{align}
a'p+[a\pmod p]&=a,\\
b'p+[b\pmod p]&=b.
\end{align}

Let's multiply both sides to obtain

\begin{align}
ab 
&= a'b'p^2\\
&+a'p\cdot[b\pmod p]\\
&+b'p\cdot[a\pmod p]\\
&+[a\pmod p]\cdot[b\pmod p].
\end{align}

You see that when you divide this by $p$, the first three terms divide perfectly as they are multiples of $p$. The only term that can contribute to the remainder of $ab$ divided by $p$ is the last part. Thats why

$$[ab\pmod p]=[a\pmod p]\cdot[b\pmod p].$$

As the left side is just your first line and defines $n$, the whole product on the left side is also $n$ which was exactly the equation you were asking about.

---

A word on notation: usually $\pmod p$ suggests, that the preceding equation (with an $\equiv$ sign) has to be interpreted "modulo p". This means, that the right and the left side of the equation has *the same remainder when divided by $p$*, but are not necessarily equal in general.

Writing $n\pmod p$ has no value (or meaning) itself, except you interpret it as the remainder itself, which is quite uncommon. One writes usually $n \text{ mod } p$ for this. I just adapted your notation for this answer but I would not suggest to use it.

General rule: $=$ means the numbers are *exactly equal*, while $\equiv$ means (in this case) that the remainders are equal when succeeded by $\pmod p$.

---

This equation is called *homomorphy rule* because it describes a ring homomorphism $\phi$ between $\Bbb Z$ and $\Bbb Z_p$, the ring consisting of the integers $0,...,p-1$ with addition and multiplication modulo $p$. When you asume $\phi(n)$ is the "remainder operator" $n\pmod p$, then the above statement can be written as

$$\phi(a\cdot b)=\phi(a)\cdot\phi(b),$$

which is a defining property of homomorphisms.

Comment: I'll adopt how you wrote the mod. I only did not know what instead of `\pmod` I could use, but didn't think about something like `\text {}` ;)

Comment: I think I get it. To multiply you used binomial rule. However, I have one thing, that I am still stuck with and which is caused probably by my awkward notation: `n'p + [n mod p] = n` wouldn't it have to be `n'p + n equiv n (mod p)` in proper notation? Because if `n>p` then the equation seems to be wrong.

Comment: $n'p+n\equiv n\pmod p$ is a tautology (always true, does not contain new information) and is not equivalent to the statement before. Maybe if I use usual notation it will become clearer. Assume $n$ divided by $p$ gives $n'$ and some remainder $r$. Written clearly, this means $n'p + r = n$. $r$ is between $0$ and $p-1$.

Comment: Ah, thanks! Now I understand it. Seems much of my own confusion was because of my weird notation.